# Android: My broadcast receiver for alarm manager isn't working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I want my alarm manager to be set for a certain time to change the phone background, but the broadcast receiver isn't doing anything. Can you help tell me why?

Scheduling alarm:

```
public void scheduleAlarm(Context context){
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 34);
    am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent );
    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Broadcast Receiver:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        GrilledCheeseLookup.getGrilledCheeseJSON(grilledCheeseUrls, context);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm worked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Enabling in manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" android:enabled="true" />
```

Comment: Do you have the `<receiver>` element in the correct spot in the manifest; i.e., between the `<application>` tags, but not inside anything else, like an `<activity>`? Are you sure the `name` attribute is pointing to the right class, in the right package? Assuming you're using the `Toast` to determine if the Receiver is running, are you sure something in `onReceive()` isn't failing before it shows?

Comment: Yes, it is within the application tag but outside any other tags like <activity>. I don't have the AlarmReceiver in any package so that should also be fine. And I am sure it isn't failing before it shows.

Comment: www.github.com/Akash14204 .. the project student budget tracker . I have used it .U can take code from there

Comment: Are you waiting a bit to give it a chance to fire the first time? Are you force-stopping the app somehow before the alarm fires?

Comment: Yes, I've waited a bit with the app in the background. does the app have to be active in order for it to work? I get my toast saying that the alarm has been set.

Comment: Nope, unless you've got some wacky device that clamps down on apps' background activity. Does your device have any additional settings or permissions beyond the standard ones, or some kind of security management app, that might be interfering? Your posted code is fine, and if the manifest entry is correct, this should be working. I mean, you've got the time right, yeah?

Comment: Try to set the alarm once using `AlarmManager.set()` to see if it will go off at all. Add logging to your `onReceive()` and check logcat to see if it was called. `Toast` is not a reliable debugging aid.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your Intent while also specifying the packageContext, using the Intent/4 constructor (you can set the uri to null).